# Comparing measures of spatial autocorrelation in residuals

Tags: autocorrelation, spatial

*1) In different regressions*

Say first regression is: $y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + u $

And the second is : $y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3 + v $

Are Moran's I values on residuals $u$ and $v$ are comparable to each other?

*2) For different samples:*

Say first regression is $y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 +  \beta_3 x_3 + u$ and sample size $n$ is $N$.

Say second regression is the same: $y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3 + v$. But the sample is subsampled based on a condition as $x_1> median(x_1)$, resulting in a change in $n$. In this case $n=N/2$. 
Are Moran's I values on residuals $u$ and $v$ are comparable to each other?

Note that Moran's I calculation assumes the residuals are i.i.d normal variables and outputs observed, expected value, variance and standart-deviate for each calculation. Importantly, assume the domain is the same for each regression and $cov(x_1, v)=0$.

Any comment is appreciated. Thank you.